# Zingchart dynamically changing axis label with Jquery

Tags: jquery, visualization, data-visualization, zingchart

I am working on this zingchart:

```
    var myConfig = {
        type: "line",
        plot:{
            aspect:"spline"
        },
      //...... legend, preview...
        "scale-x":{
                "format":"%v",
                "zooming":true,
                "label":{
                    "id": "xlabel",
                    "text":"X",
                    "margin-top":100
                },
                "item":{
                    "auto-align":true,
                    "maxChars":10
                },
                "tick":{
                    "line-color":"black",
                    "line-width":"2px",
                    "size":8
                } 
        },
        "scale-y":{
                "zooming":true,
                "decimals":0,
                "label":{
                    "id": "ylabel",
                    "text":"Y",
                    "margin-top":100
                }
        },
        series: [
                { "values": [
                        [1,10],
                        [2,20],
                        [3,50],
                        [4,60]
                    ]
                },
                { "values": [
                        [1,3],
                        [2,7],
                        [3,15],
                        [4,30],
                        [5,70],
                        [3.2,25]
                    ]
                }
            ]
    };
```

I have modified the graph to add plots, etc. However, I get an error when trying to modify dynamically the labels of the X and Y axes. I am using the JQuery wrapper and according to [Update Object](https://github.com/zingchart/ZingChart-jQuery#updateobject-object-) I do:

```
$('#myChart').updateObject({
             "type": "label",
                "data": {
                    "id": "xlabel",
                    "text": "My new label"
                }
            });
```

But this raises an error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined` on this part (I know it is minimised and will not make too much sense unless you developed zingchart):

```
 for (z = 0, b = p.length; z < b; z++) {
```

in the `case "updateobject":`

I am unsure I am using the object update correctly, but this is how it seems to work from the documentation. Any ideas I might be missing?

**EDIT:**
I could not reproduce the incidence in this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ztj0agbs/), but I could not make it work either.

**EDIT2:**

I think it comes to this bit, where it sets `p` to `undefined`:

```
case "updateobject":
    r = n.BY(e[ZC._[3]]);
    if (r && e.data) {
        r.G["objects.updates"] = []; //G = "label"
        G = e.type || "label";  // e = Object {type: "label", data: Object}
        p = r.o[G + "s"];   // p = undefined, r = e {b: undefined, M9: "zcgraph", MW: "linegraph", o: Object, G: Object…}
```

And `r.o` is:

```
o: Object
background-color: "#ffffff"
height: 502
legend: Object
plot: Object
plotarea: Object
preview: Object
scale-x: Object
scale-y: Object
series: Array[2]
tween: null
type: "line"
width: 755
x: 0
y: 0
__proto__: Object
```

This [Demo](http://www.zingchart.com/docs/developers/api-methods/#zingchart__exec__api__updateobject) shows an example where `UpdateObject` works:

```
var myConfig = {
    'type':'line',
    'series':[
        {
            'values':[11,26,7,44,11]
        }
    ],
    'labels':[
       {
            'id':'label1',
           'text':'Label 1',
            'x':50,
          'y':50,
          'background-color':'#f90',
           'padding':5
      },{
          'id':'label2',
           'text':'Label 2',
            'x':150,
         'y':50,
          'background-color':'#f09',
           'padding':5
      }
    ],
    'shapes':[
      {
            'id':'shape1',
           'x':100,
         'y':100,
```

It seems that the object under `labels` will be found (that is why I saw before a `+"s"` in `p = r.o[G + "s"]`). It might mean that I am using the wrong method to modify the label inside the "scale-x".

Comment: can you share a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#myChart").modify({
    "data": {
         "scale-x":{
            "label":{
                "id": "xlabel",
                "text":"My new label",
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: ZingChart team member here. The reason you have to use modify instead of updateObject is because updateObject only targets shapes and labels in the top-level shapes and labels objects. The updateObject was looking for a top level labels array and didn't find it, thus the "cannot read length of undefined" error. A scale label is a child of the scale object and thus any changes to it change the scale object itself. Just wanted to offer some insight into the issue. Glad to see the jQuery wrapper getting used!

Comment: Thanks! I realised that after some debugging.... and the documentation was clear but I interpreted differently